# Why the last function is not returning you have no question

Tags: javascript

I am supposed to get you have no question in the queue since the last three questions I don't know why the last console should return you have no question in the queue. Does it return the current question or is there anything wrong with my codes.

```
var student = {};
student.firstName = 'W';
student.lastName = 'H';
student.age = '21';
student.school = 'UofA';
student.questionQueue = [];
student.hasQuestion = false;
student.greeting = function(){return "Hello, my name is " + this.firstName;}
student.aboutMe = function(){return "My full name is " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + ", " + "I am " + this.age + " years old and I am a student at " + this.school;}
student.askQuestion = function(question){
  this.questionQueue.push(question);
  this.hasQuestion = !this.hasQuestion;
  return "A question has been added to your queue";
}
student.answerQuestion = function(){
  if(student.hasQuestion === true){
    var currentQuestion = this.questionQueue.pop();
    if (student.questionQueue.length === 0) {
      student.hasQuestion === false;
    }
    return currentQuestion;
  }
  else if(student.hasQuestion === false){
    return "You have no questions in your queue";
  }
}

console.log('Greet Test:', student.greeting());
console.log('AboutMe Test:', student.aboutMe());
console.log('Answer Question Test:', student.answerQuestion());
console.log('Ask Question Test:', student.askQuestion('Why is the Earth flat?'));
console.log('Ask Question Test:', student.askQuestion('Why is the sky green?'));
console.log('Ask Question Test:', student.askQuestion('Why don\'t birds have wings'));
console.log('Answer Question Test:', student.answerQuestion());
console.log('Answer Question Test:', student.answerQuestion());
console.log('Answer Question Test:', student.answerQuestion());
console.log('Answer Question Test:', student.answerQuestion());
```

Comment: `if (student.questionQueue.length === 0) { student.hasQuestion === false; }` I think that here you don't want to compare, but to set a value, so use `... = false` not  `... === false`

Answer (score 1):

```
this.hasQuestion = !this.hasQuestion;
```

must be

```
this.hasQuestion = true;
```

By asking a question, you are just inversing your boolean again and again. It does not make any sens.

and

```
if (student.questionQueue.length === 0)
  student.hasQuestion === false;
```

must be

```
if (student.questionQueue.length === 0)
  student.hasQuestion = false;
```

You are just testing the value of your boolean while you want to change it.